# Cloning vs fresh install

Tags: linux, disk-cloning

I have to create roughly 3-5 systems a year which ship with software A. They use the same base Linux Debian operating system with the same modules and settings, though A's version and database parameters vary.
I was wondering what would be the most efficient way to create these - whether through a fresh install from .iso image of the Debian OS version, or through cloning an existing system and simply changing the software.

Fundamentally, is cloning (e.g. through dd) more error-prone than installing a new .iso (e.g. through dd) and manually configuring settings?

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: There's also the option of `rsync` / `(bsd)tar`. And practice makes perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I used to work for a pharmaceutical company, and we had to migrate like 150+ pcs from Windows 7->10 and some Ubuntu (tho they were like 10-15).

Speaking from personal experience, i had a lot of troubles cloning even if the PC i did the clone with was in EXCELLENT condition, so i just resorted to fresh installs whenever possible, i would not advise to clone if you're doing just 3-5 installations a year.. Maybe try to automatize software installation & configuration rather than cloning.

Also cloning problems seem to be really hard to pinpoint when you have any kind of issue, at least on Windows it was like that.

Hope it helps! And good luck.

Comment: Thank you, so it's as I suspected with cloning. I will probably look into making custom ISO's, which would be easiest in the long run (if not short term).